# Why the converse in this theorem is false : $E[|X_{n} - X|] \rightarrow 0$ then $X_{n} \rightarrow_{p} X$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I know that $E[|X_{n} - X|] \rightarrow 0$ then $X_{n} \rightarrow_{p} X$, but I need to prove that the converse is false

Any help is appreciated, where $X_{n} \rightarrow_{p} X$ means for all $\epsilon >0, \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{P}[|X_{n} - X|\geq \epsilon]=0$

Comment: Convergence in $L^1$ implies convergence in probability, but the converse is not true.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the standard probability space on $[0,1]$. There, $n\mathcal{X}_{[0,1/n]} \rightarrow_p 0$, but $E[|n\mathcal{X}_{[0,1/n]}-0|]=1 \not\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: What is $n\mathcal{X}_{[0,1/n]}$?

Comment: It is $n$ times the indicator of $[0,\frac{1}{n}]$. In other words, it equals to $n$ in the interval $[0,\frac{1}{n}]$ and $0$ outside the interval.

Comment: What Mark wrote